# Looping through textboxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I go about in clearing these textboxes by looping through them using Jquery?

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="RegexInsert">
    <h4>New Regex Pattern</h4>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">Desription</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRegexDesription" placeholder="Description" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">Regex pattern</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRegexPattern" placeholder="Regex pattern(C#)" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">Data type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDataType" placeholder="Data type" />
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btnAddRegexPattern" data-applicationid=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am doing the following which is not quite there yet.

```
$("#RegexInsert .inputs").each(function () {
    $('input').val('');
});
```

kind regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a loop, you can do it in a single selector:

```
$('.form-control').val('');
```

I'm not sure where `.inputs` in your example is coming from as it is not in your HTML. You can make the selector more generic if required:

```
$('#RegexInsert input[type="text"]').val('');
```

Comment: May be this could be better. `$('#RegexInsert input.form-control').val('');`

Answer (score 6):

To clear the input elements, as noted elsewhere:

```
$("#RegexInsert .inputs").val('');
```

To *reset* the input elements' values:

```
$("#RegexInsert .inputs").val(function(){
    return this.defaultValue;
});
```

Or, if you have multiple input-types (and this is, frankly, more complex than I at first assumed it would be...):

```
$('#reset').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input, textarea, select option')
    .each(function(){
        var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase(),
            type = this.type,
            prop, value;
        if ('undefined' !== typeof type) {
            switch (type) {
                case 'radio':
                case 'checkbox':
                    prop = 'checked';
                    break;
                case 'text':
                case 'textarea': // textarea elements seem to have a type
                                 // property, undexpectedly (in Chrome/Win XP)
                    prop = 'value';
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            switch (tag) {
                case 'option':
                    prop = 'selected';
                    break;
                case 'textarea':    // left this just in case the 'type' property
                    prop = 'value'; // is a Chrome/Webkit specific thing.
                    break;
            }
        }
        this[prop] = this['default' + prop.replace(/^./,function(a){
            return a.toUpperCase();
        })];
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/V72xB/).

Comment: can anyone link me to the proper doc of `defaultValue`.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/defaultValue

Comment: Wait there is a `defaultValue` property?! I didn't know that before

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - Yea, I realized that now

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use a loop

```
$("#RegexInsert input").val('');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following :

```
$("#RegexInsert input").each(function () {
    $(this).val(); // Gets the value
    $(this).val('newValue'); // Sets the value
});
```

In your case, you have a shortcut to clean all (the each() is implicit) :

```
$("#RegexInsert input").val('');
```

Beware though as this will clean any input that has a value attribute. You may want to consider stronger selector, like `$("#RegexInsert input[type=text]")`

Answer (score 3):

do like this:

```
$('#RegexInsert input.form-control').val('');
```

or:

```
$('.form-group input.form-control').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

your original code

```
$("#RegexInsert .inputs").each(function () {
    $('input').val('');
});
```

.inputs doesn't exist anywhere in your HTML. If you are referring to the input tags, the your selector should be input.

```
$("#RegexInsert input").each(function () {
    $(this).val('');
});
```